# C++: an input validator function

Tags: c++, c++14

I have written the following function:

```
void check(int* input){

do{
    std::cout<<"Enter integer!";
    std::cin>>*input;
}while(!std::cin);
}
```

And I am using it in the main function as follows:

```
int main()
{
    int *k;
    k=new int;
    check(k);
    std::cout<<"Value of the k is:"<<*k<<"in address"<<k;
    return 0;
}
```

The problem is when user input some characters, the compiler keep printing "Enter integer!",  non-stop, and I have to stop the compiler manually.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but *why* do you allocate the integer dynamically in `main`? Why use pointers *at all*? Why not simple *references*?

Comment: As for your problem, it's well-known problem with plenty of duplicates here. It stems from the input not being removed from the buffer. You need to clear or [*ignore*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore) the existing input.

Answer (score 1):

What is happening is the stream is breaking. Basically, the program sees a character going into something that isn't a character and freaks out, which is UB. It is a simple fix you can find in just about any beginning level books that include data validation:

```
#include <limits>

if(cin.fail())
{
    cin.clear();
    cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
}
```

This tests if the stream is broken, clear the flag and ignore the rest of the input on the line.